# An elegant way to transform duplicates into indexed in Python?

Tags: python

What I want to do is to transform an array of

`['x', 'y', 'z', 'x', 'z']`

into:

`['x1', 'y', 'z1', 'x2', 'z2']`

Meaning

- if an occurrence (`'y'` here) is not duplicate, it stays as it is.
- if there is more than one occurrence (`'x'` or `'z'` here), they are suffixed by their rank.

In my case, the array size will be low (less than 20 elements, there is no performance issue).

Is it possible to do it in an elegant, short, Python expression?

Edit:

Even if I don't know if it is elegant, I finally coded this for now (no import, only one dictionary):

```
def index_duplicates( l ):
    def get_indexed( d, s ):
        c = d[s]
        if c: d[s] = c + 1
        return s + str(c) if c else s
    d = {}
    for s in l: d[s] = 1 if s in d else 0
    return (get_indexed(d, s) for s in l)
```

So that:

```
[x for x in index_duplicates(l)]
```

returns the result.

Comment: Just figured that out and deleted the comment @lemon

Comment: Is it important to keep the order of the elements ?

Comment: @vlemaistre, yes it is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Original version - `O(n^2)`

Without imports, we can do the following naive implementation:

```
arr = ['x', 'y', 'z', 'x', 'z']
out = []
for i in range(len(arr)):
    c = arr[i]
    if arr.count(c) > 1:
        out.append(c + str(arr[:i].count(c) + 1))
    else:
        out.append(c)
```

```
>>> out
['x1', 'y', 'z1', 'x2', 'z2']
```

---

#### Efficient version - `O(n)`

If we want to have a better time complexity, we can pass through the list once to get the total count of each unique character in the list. Then, we can iterate through the list a second time, caching the counts of characters as we go along and using that to get our answer.

```
arr = ['x', 'y', 'z', 'x', 'z']
out = []
totals = dict()
freqs = dict() # Track all character counts

# Get the total count of every unique character in the list
for i, c in enumerate(arr):
    if c in totals:
        totals[c] += 1
    else:
        totals[c] = 1

for i, c in enumerate(arr):
    total = totals[c] # Get total character count
    # Count how many have been seen so far during the second traversal
    if c in freqs:
        freqs[c] += 1
    else:
        freqs[c] = 1
    out.append(c + str(freqs[c]) if total > 1 else c)
```

```
>>> out
['x1', 'y', 'z1', 'x2', 'z2']
```

Comment: not from me also, but maybe from the fact that this will be `O(n^2)`

Comment: @Tomerikoo Good point, I'll try to make a more efficient version and add it to my answer.

Comment: @AndrejKesely Thanks! I have added the more efficient version now.

Comment: @StardustGogeta I've already upvoted :) Op should accept this answer, there's nice explanation.

Comment: `arr.count` is an O(n) operation that must be performed on each unique element in the array, so this is still O(n^2) worst case complexity (where the array contains all distinct items).  You can simplify via `for i, c in enumerate(arr):`.

Comment: @Alexander Alright, I think I finally fixed it up properly. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, it is much improved in regards to the time complexity. The code can be further simplified by using a defaultdict for your counters (`freqs` & `totals`) (https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples) or a counter from `itertools` (https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.count).

Comment: @StardustGogeta, thanks. Accepted. FYI, have edited the question though with some code. Please comment on it if some remarks or suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

Using `collections.Counter` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)) and `itertools.count` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.count)):

```
from itertools import count
from collections import Counter

lst = ['x', 'y', 'z', 'x', 'z']

c, counters = Counter(lst), {i:count(1) for i in set(lst)}

new_lst = ['{}{}'.format(i, next(counters[i])) if c[i] > 1 else i for i in lst]

print(new_lst)
```

Prints:

```
['x1', 'y', 'z1', 'x2', 'z2']
```

EDIT (Another version using only `collections.Counter`):

```
import collections

lst = ['x', 'y', 'z', 'x', 'z']

counts = collections.Counter(lst)
counts2 = dict(**counts)

for i, v in enumerate(reversed(lst), start=1):
    if counts2[v] > 1:
        lst[-i] = v + str(counts[v])
        counts[v] -= 1

print(lst)
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you want `y` to remain unchanged if there is only one occurrence of that item, one must first pass through every element of the array to check for duplicates.

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

arr = ['x', 'y', 'z', 'x', 'z']

dd = defaultdict(int)
c = Counter(arr)
single_occurrence_set = {k for k, v in c.items() if v == 1}

result = []
for item in arr:
    dd[item] += 1
    result.append(item if item in single_occurrence_set else f'{item}{dd[item]}')

>>> result
['x1', 'y', 'z1', 'x2', 'z2']
```

If `y` could become `y1`, then the code is simplified, as `Counter` and `single_occurrences` are no longer required.

```
dd = defaultdict(int)
result = []
for item in arr:
    dd[item] += 1
    result.append(f'{item}{dd[item]}')

>>> result
['x1', 'y1', 'z1', 'x2', 'z2']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
from collections import Counter


l = ['x', 'y', 'z', 'x', 'z']
count = Counter(l)
current = {k:1 for k in l}

new_l = []
for val in l:
    data = val
    # Do we have a duplicate?
    if count[val] > 1:
        data += str(current[val])
        current[val] += 1

    new_l.append(data)

print(new_l)
# ['x1', 'y', 'z1', 'x2', 'z2']
```

Answer (score 2):

If the order of the elements is not important, this solution is the most concise (though it may not be the fastest) :

```
# We use np.unique to get the unique elements and their number of occurences
counts = np.unique(l,return_counts=True)

# We use a double list comprehension to get the expected result
["{}_{}".format(x, z) if y>1 else x for x, y in zip(counts[0], counts[1]) 
                                         for z in range(1, y+1)]
```